# How to fit an image perfectly inside GridView Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gridview, imageview

I am trying to create a project where I used a **GridView** to show images. But the problem is images can have various sizes. Some of them are big, some of them are small. So I want to fit the images in GridView perfectly. But whatever I try nothing makes it better. The following photo can clear more-

[image]

I want the pictures to be **square sized and center-cropped** but they are vertically stretched for some reason.

The relevant code snippets are below-

**ImageView code**

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/gridImage"/>
```

**GridView code**

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="3dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/line" />
```

**GridAdapter code**

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if(inflater==null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) cx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(view == null)
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.gridImage);
    Pictures p = pictures.get(i);
    Glide.with(cx).load(p.getImageID()).centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.avatar).into(imageView);
    return view;
}
```

I tried all the scaleTypes of ImageView but none of them made the images square, center-cropped and perfectly fitted inside the GridView. Am I missing something here?

Comment: try to use fitSystemWindows = "true" , you can also crop each image so you are sure about each one width and height.

Comment: try to change the layout_height constraint of the imageview from match_parent to wrap_content

Comment: Neither of those worked. How to crop each image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android:adjustViewBounds="true" or android:scaleType="fitXY" for VIew please refer this [enter link description here](https://proandroiddev.com/a-guide-for-android-imageview-scaletype-and-adjustviewbounds-64a1e4a35503#:%7E:text=and%20without%20adjustViewBounds-,adjustViewBounds%3Dtrue,it%20gets%20centered%20in%20it.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Which view? ImageView? I tried fitXY for the ImageView, it didn’t work. Matter of fact, it made it worse.

Comment: have you tried adjustviewbounds yes, on imageview

Comment: WOW! The adjustviewbounds actually worked! Thank you so much. I have been trying so hard to solve this problem. Will you please edit your answer with details as the community bot said so that I can accept it for this question? @rv_5143

Comment: see i edited now if it's work//

Comment: That would do the trick. Thanks again.

Comment: ohh pleasure is always mine dear :D @Newbie_programmer

Answer (score 0):

You can use well know 3rd party libraries like picasso or glide to load images into ImageView, which is quite easy compared to native loading. As we compared native loading with picasso/glide, native loading has several drawbacks like memory leak, complexity and consistency. While you can achieve what you want from glide/picasso with ease.

Comment: The pictures were loaded using Glide. The pictures are actually some links from Firebase Database. I used an adapter and within that adapter I loaded those uri links inside "Glide" to show the pictures.

Comment: If you can provide more java/Kotlin code, on how did you setup glide it would be helpful. I have used this code to center crop image "Glide.with(this).load(userData.results[0].picture.large).centerCrop().into(binding.ivImageGlide)"

Comment: Please check the question again, I added the GridAdapter code snippet. I also used centerCrop like you used but it's the same thing, stretched vertically!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).